# JS. Creating a if statement, not receiving the results of matching data

Tags: javascript

[Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u51pr.png)

As a newbie, I am having a nick at trying to understand if else, currently I believe I wrote the correct condition for this, however I am not getting the return I wanted. This is an assignment I am following.

```
var cards = ["Queen", "Queen", "King", "King"];

var cardsInPlay = [];

// Variables assigned cards

var cardOne = cards[0];
var cardTwo = cards[2];
var cardThree = [];
var cardFour = [];

// Pushing the elements into the "cardsInPlay variable"

cardsInPlay.push(cardOne);
cardsInPlay.push(cardTwo);

if (cardsInPlay === cards.length[2]) {
alert("Sorry, try again.");
} else if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
alert("You found a match!");
}
```

This is the code I have written so far. A, I doing this correctly?

Comment: `cards.length[2]` should return an error, you are trying to index a number.

Comment: @Maria Actually it will be `undefined`. It won't throw an error.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara ah okay, JavaScript...

Comment: I am attempting to write an if statement that checks to see if the length of the cardsInPlay array is 2 but I am not sure if I am writing it out correctly.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at debugging this? Just spam `alert` or `console.log` on every value and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment states that you need to check if the length of the cardsInPlay array is 2, so:

```
if(cardsInPlay.length === 2){

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was able to figure this out after that. The full code ended up being: if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
console.log("you have selected two cards");
if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) 
alert("You found a match!");
else
alert("Sorry, try again");
}